# Is it possible to sum a column with pdfmake library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdfmake

I want to sum a column to get grand total from a pdf file generated by [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake)

Sample Data:

```
#ID ItemName Description          Unit  Qty  Amount    Subtotal
1   Mawe     Misumari ya ukuta    KG    10    3,000.00  30,000.00
2   Mawe     Misumari ya ukuta    PCS   10   50,000.00 500,000.00
3   Mawe     Kwa ajili ya misingi KG    20    3,000.00  60,000.00
```

So i want to sum the Subtotal Column with pdfmake during export and get something like

```
#ID ItemName Description          Unit  Qty  Amount    Subtotal
1   Mawe     Misumari ya ukuta    KG    10    3,000.00  30,000.00
2   Mawe     Misumari ya ukuta    PCS   10   50,000.00 500,000.00
3   Mawe     Kwa ajili ya misingi KG    20    3,000.00  60,000.00
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Total:                                                 590,000.00
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, i've solved it i just used here is the solution i think it might help someone out there.
Hope the code is readable and easy to understand. Thanks again.

```
"footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                    var api = this.api(), data;
                    var intVal = function ( i ) {
                        return typeof i === 'string' ?
                            i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                            typeof i === 'number' ?
                                i : 0;
                    };
                    total = api
                        .column( 6 ) //Getting the column # i want to sum
                        .data()
                        .reduce( function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0 );
                    pageTotal = api
                        .column( 6, { page: 'current'} ) 
                        .data()
                        .reduce( function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0 );
                    $( api.column( 6 ).footer() ).html(
                        'TZS '+ pageTotal.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") +'/='+
                        '( TZS '+ total.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") +'/= total)'
                    );
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

we can also calculate in view page manually by this

```
<?php $total=0; ?>  
                                    <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
                                            <?php $total += $row['Subtotal'];?>

                                        <?php endforeach ?>
```

And we can display it by `<?php echo"$total_qty"?>`

Answer (score 0):

No. PDFMake makes PDFs but it's not a calculator not it really cares about the content it prints. You need to sum stuff up yourself.